# Citrix 4.0- app will not minimize to system tray?

Tags: windows-server-2003, citrix, ms-office-communicator

I have MS Office Communicator 2005 published on a Citrix presentation server VS 4.0. When a user minimizes the contacts window it minimizes to the task bar, which I fine.  However if they close the application using the X it does not minimize to the users local system tray, instead it minimizes to lala land on the Citrix server.  Then the user has to log off using the Citrix connection manager, which closes OC, thus signing them out.

I believe, but cannot confirm, that the contacts window use to minimize to the system tray. As for what changed?? Nothing that I am aware off. But that doesn’t mean much!  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When you click the X, do you still see it running in task manager on the local machine? I'm assuming you are running your apps in seamless mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out

Another admin had...

http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX101644&searchID=26517783
DISABLE SYSTRAY AGENT